# How to specify custom order of options in SearchPanes for DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a custom search pane that I would like to have options shown in specific order.

Here is the pane definition:

```
                    {
                        header: "Dzień",
                        options: [
                            { label: 'poniedziałek', value: function(rowData, rowIdx) { return dayOfWeek(this, rowIdx, "MONDAY"); } },
                            { label: 'wtorek',       value: function(rowData, rowIdx) { return dayOfWeek(this, rowIdx, "TUESDAY"); } },
                            { label: 'środa',        value: function(rowData, rowIdx) { return dayOfWeek(this, rowIdx, "WEDNESDAY"); } },
                            { label: 'czwartek',     value: function(rowData, rowIdx) { return dayOfWeek(this, rowIdx, "THURSDAY"); } },
                            { label: 'piątek',       value: function(rowData, rowIdx) { return dayOfWeek(this, rowIdx, "FRIDAY"); } },
                            { label: 'sobota',       value: function(rowData, rowIdx) { return dayOfWeek(this, rowIdx, "SATURDAY"); } },
                            { label: 'niedziela',    value: function(rowData, rowIdx) { return dayOfWeek(this, rowIdx, "SUNDAY"); } }
                        ],
                        dtOpts: {
                            searching: false
                        }
                    },
```

The above orders the options alphabetically and I would prefer to specify the order myself, e.g. by assigning a number to each option. Is it possible with SearchPanes? I couldn't find builtin option to do that.

Also, besides the custom panes, is it possible to do similar ordering on non-custom panes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a render function to the `dtOpts` option, and use orthogonal data to define a custom sort order for the display:

```js
dtOpts: {
  searching: false,
  columnDefs: [ { 
    targets: [0], 
    render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      if (type === 'sort') {
        var dayNum;
        switch(data) {
          case 'poniedziałek':
            dayNum = 1;
            break;
          case 'wtorek':
            dayNum = 2;
            break;
          case 'środa':
            dayNum = 3;
            break;
          case 'czwartek':
            dayNum = 4;
            break;
          case 'piątek':
            dayNum = 5;
            break;
          case 'sobota':
            dayNum = 6;
            break;
          case 'niedziela':
            dayNum = 7;
            break;
        }
        return dayNum; 
      } else {
       return data;
     }
    }
  } ],
  order: [[0, 'asc']] // you may not need this line
}
```

This works because (a) the pane is itself a small DataTable, and (b) the `dtOpts` option allows you to specify standard DataTables options targeting the pane.

You probably don't need the `order: [[0, 'asc']]` - I expect the pane will use that anyway as the default. But I included it just in case, because I don't have any test data for the main table.

My end result:

[image]

---

I have not tried it, but I assume you can do the same for non-custom panes (i.e. they will need this customization, too.)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed.